# "list users" in Cassandra is extremely slow

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm running Cassandra version 2.0.14. 
When I run list users from cqlsh in Cassandra, the query is extremely slow and it takes around 5 minutes to see the results. 
The same goes for querying system_auth.users. This table is really small (only 2 users), so I don't understand why it takes so long to see the results. 
Nodetool cfstats doesn't show any read/write latency on the users table.

Any idea?

Comment: Try to query with `TRACING ON`. Might get some clue

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip!
I see that for some reason it request data from all nodes in all of the DCs.
So that makes me wonder... Why does it do that, if the system_auth keyspace has a replication factor of 1 (simple strategy). 
In addition, I see the following: "Executing seq scan across 0 sstables for (max(9211875219149852128), max(9219147408444189208)]". 
How come I see 0 SSTables although there is definitely one SStable in the system_auth keyspace?